# appending like data when Joining two tables when two columns of one table refer to a third one in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, yajra-datatable

I have three tables. items, authors, and author_item which pairs an author_id with item_id.

I am successfully selecting everything I need from items and authors using the third table when joining.

The problem I am having is that there are sometimes two or three authors that go with one item and I would like to append all matching authors to one item row.

````
$publications = \DB::table('items')
   ->select('items.pub_number', 'items.title', 'authors.first_name', 'authors.last_name', 'items.published_date', 'items.updated_at')
   ->leftjoin('author_item', 'items.id', '=', 'author_item.item_id')
   ->leftjoin('authors', 'author_item.author_id', '=', 'authors.id')
   ->where('items.is_product', false); ```
````

for a visible representation, I will demonstrate below.

I would like

```
| Pub # | Title | Authors      | Published  | Revision  |
| ------| ------| -----------  | 1989-09-03 | 2020-10-05|
| 138   | beledo|Jaeden Pouros | 1989-09-03 | 2020-10-05|
| 138   | beledo|Jennifer Lexy | 1989-09-03 | 2020-10-05|
| 145   | argade|Alex Johnson  | 1989-09-03 | 2020-10-05|
```

To become

```
| Pub # | Title | Authors                     | Published  | Revision  |
| ------| ------| --------------------------- | 1989-09-03 | 2020-10-05|
| 138   | beledo|Jaeden Pouros, Jennifer Lexy | 1989-09-03 | 2020-10-05|
| 145   | argade|Alex Johnson                 | 1989-09-03 | 2020-10-05|
```

This is being queried into Yajra Datatables so if I am able to accomplish this by altering my query instead that would make this a lot less complex.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inner join if you only need the matched rows from three tables

```
$publications = \DB::table('items')
 ->select('items.pub_number', 'items.title', 'authors.first_name', 'authors.last_name', 'items.published_date', 'items.updated_at')
   ->join('author_item', 'items.id', '=', 'author_item.item_id')
   ->join('authors', 'author_item.author_id', '=', 'authors.id')
   ->where('items.is_product', false);
```

Because
The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (author_item, authors), and the matched records from the right table. The result is NULL from the right side if there is no match
And
The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.